# How to substitute all the values in a two-dimensional array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, string-substitution

I have a two-dimensional array looking like this:

```
[true,false,false]
[false,true,false]
[false,false,true]
```

I wish I could substitute all the **true(bool)** values with **'true'(string)** and all the **false** with **'false'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of arrays:

```
a = [[true,false,false], [false,true,false], [false,false,true]]
a.each { |x| x.map!(&:to_s) }
a # => [["true", "false", "false"], ["false", "true", "false"], ["false", "false", "true"]]
```

Comment: Not thread-safe. Arup's answer using map twice was better. Voting to undelete his...

Comment: @Denis Thread-safety wasn't a requirement in the OP. `Array` in MRI isn't thread-safe either.

Comment: @Denis You can't  in fact *know* the best answer since you don't know the *exact requirements*. You're making an assumption that thread-safety is an issue here although the OP says nothing about it.

Comment: I'm simply pointing out that one answer leaves a dangling, hard to trace bug that will blow up in your face should it ever be used in a thread, whereas the other doesn't. In that light, the latter is simply better than the former.

Comment: @Denis On the other hand, performance-wise this is better than the other answer.

Comment: Whether performance or thread-safety is more important is to be decided based on the nature of the problem at-hand. Making  assumptions is no good.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, do as below using [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
a = [[true,false,false], [false,true,false], [false,false,true]]
# you can also assign this to a new local variable instead of a,
# if you need to use your source array object in future anywhere.
a = a.map { |e| e.map(&:to_s) }
```